# Why does my three.js code not execute on MacOS? Error: "Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call". It works fine on Windows

Tags: javascript, macos, three.js

**What it should do:**

Animate a Line from the center of the screen to the current Mouse-Position.

**Problem:**

It only works on Windows systems.

i made a simplified codepen to show the problem:

https://codepen.io/ascheschleier/pen/qBLeRzN

It runs fine on win and doesn't run on osX. Codepen does not give a console output, but if i run the same code directly in a macOS browser (safari or chrome), the error given is:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call.
```

Since the error and various [sources](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/vertex-buffer-is-not-big-enough-for-the-draw-call-only-on-mac-computers/43628/8) say its a buffer length issue, i tried to set different values at Lines 36 and 55 where the Buffer sizes are defined, with no luck.

I am not very fluent in three.js yet, so not sure if my thinking is right, but the `positions = new Float32Array` has the start and endpoint (x,y,z) so the size should be 6. And the `threeBufferPosition = new THREE.BufferAttribute` wants the length of each point, so 3 should be right. It gives an error if set to 6 instead of 3 anyways.

I need Help figuring out what is wrong with the buffer sizes, or where else the error might come from.

EDIT:
the code from the codepen:

```
class Line {
    constructor(_start, _end) {  
        this.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        this.material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial( {
            color: 0xffffff,
            linewidth: 1,
            scale: 1,
            dashSize: 1, // to be updated in the render loop
            gapSize: 1e10 // a big number, so only one dash is rendered
    
        } );            
        this.positions = new Float32Array( 6 ); // 3 vertices per point     
        this.start = new THREE.Vector3( _start.x, _start.y, 0 );
        this.end = new THREE.Vector3( _end.x, _end.y, 0 );
        this.lineDistance = new Float32Array( 1 );
        this.lineDistance[0] = this.start.distanceTo(this.end);
        
        this.positions[ 0 ] = this.start.x;
        this.positions[ 1 ] = this.start.y;
        this.positions[ 2 ] = this.start.z;
        this.positions[ 3 ] = this.end.x;
        this.positions[ 4 ] = this.end.y;
        this.positions[ 5 ] = this.end.z;
        this.fraction = 0;
        this.isFinished = false;
        this.lineLength = this.lineDistance;
        this.growRate =  0.01;
        this.growMax = 1;

        this.threeBufferPosition = new THREE.BufferAttribute( this.positions, 3 );
        this.geometry.setAttribute( 'position',  this.threeBufferPosition);
        this.geometry.setAttribute( 'lineDistance', new THREE.BufferAttribute( this.lineDistance, 1 ) );
        this.line = new THREE.Line( this.geometry, this.material );
        scene.add( this.line );
      
        this.startcaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.endcaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    }
    
    update(_start,_end) {
            const positions = this.line.geometry.attributes.position.array;
      this.startcaster.setFromCamera(_start, camera);
      this.endcaster.setFromCamera(_end, camera);
      let start = new THREE.Vector3(_start.x, _start.y, 0);
      let end  = new THREE.Vector3(_end.x, _end.y, 0);
      this.startcaster.ray.at(1, start);
      this.endcaster.ray.at(1, end);
      
            positions[ 0 ] = start.x;
            positions[ 1 ] = start.y;
            positions[ 2 ] = start.z;      
            positions[ 3 ] = end.x;
            positions[ 4 ] = end.y;
            positions[ 5 ] = end.z;             
      
            this.line.geometry.getAttribute( 'position' ).needsUpdate = true;
        }

        animate() {         
            if(this.fraction < this.growMax) {
                this.fraction = ( this.fraction + this.growRate );
                this.line.material.dashSize = this.fraction * this.lineLength;
            }
        }
    }
  
  let line = new Line({x:-1,y:-1}, {x:0,y:0});
    
  $(document).on("mousemove" , function(e) {  
      const mX = e.pageX;
      const mY = e.pageY;            

      let normalizedCoords = calculate2DPoint({x: mX, y:mY});
      line.update(normalizedCoords, {x:0,y:0});
  });
  
  
  animate();
  function animate(){
    line.animate();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      animate();
    });
  }
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/vertex-buffer-is-not-big-enough-for-the-draw-call-only-on-mac-computers/43628/7

Comment: i linked to that in my question, so i found it before asking and it did not help. but thanks!

Comment: sorry, missed that

Comment: Please show your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conceptual issue in your line drawing code. You create a line geometry with two vertices defining the line but only one distance value. Rendering primitives doesn't work like that. You have to manage data on vertex level so you need one distance value per vertex. I suggest you use `0` as the distance for the first vertex and then the real distance from the beginning of the line for all subsequent vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! it is very possible that i use the primitives wrong, since i struggle to understand where the first distance should be applied? i tried to add `this.lineDistance = new Float32Array( 2 ); this.lineDistance[0] = 0;` and initialize the buffer with `this.geometry.setAttribute( 'lineDistance', new THREE.BufferAttribute( this.lineDistance, 2 ) );` but that seems to be wrong still.
could you be so kind and elaborate how to do it correctly?

Comment: okay, if i have two distances and set the buffer with `this.geometry.setAttribute( 'lineDistance', new THREE.BufferAttribute( this.lineDistance, 1 ) );` it works on macOS, still don't really understand why, but maked as solved, thanks!